# how to automatically zoom to cropped image in GIMP

Tags: gimp

Whenever I use the cropping tool in GIMP, I must zoom in to the cropped image manually afterwards and center it. Is there an option that GIMP will automatically zoom to the cropped content?

thanks,
Sina

tried youtube tutorials, but found nothing there...